# Eclipse Version for GWT

Tags: gwt

What version of Eclipse do I need for Google Web Toolkit? I see about 7 versions, but none make any references to GWT. Google doesn't mention it to. I did install the PHP version.

Answer (score 5):

Definitely the Java EE version. The regular java version doesn't seem to work with the google plugin.

Answer (score 3):

Since GWT means Java programming I would recommend the Java (default) Version of Eclipse or Java EE Version because they contain the Java Development Tools which will help you very when coding in Java

Answer (score 2):

Well I download the Eclipse for Java EE:

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/heliossr2

But one which is great is Spring STS (based on eclipse). You can choose to install GWT at the beginning.

http://www.springsource.com/downloads/sts

Comment: +1 STS has lots of GWT and GAE tools out of the box including Roo for rails like scaffolding to get you started quickly.

Comment: That link to STS gives a 404. The current link is [http://spring.io/tools/sts/](http://spring.io/tools/sts/).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you should install JavaEE version.. Because GWT produce a war file, and it should be deployed to a  web application server.